# How can I calculate a beta regression prediction from the coefficients?

Tags: regression, logistic, beta-regression

I have applied the R betareg function to my data using the default logit link and phi precision log-link for the categorical data. My equation is:

```
betareg(formula = proportion ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 + 
    1 | categorical_variable, data = data_train)
```

I have a series of beta values: b0 = intercept, b1 to b5 are the coefficients for the feature variables, and then there are constants for each of the categorical variables.
I would like to predict a proportion using all these coefficients.

I understand that the logit link reverse equation is:
`proportion = 1/(1+exp(-lp))`,
or equivalently, `proportion = exp(lp)/(1+exp(lp))`

where `lp = b0 + b1*var1 + b2*var2 + b3*var3 + b4*var4 + b5*var5`,

However, I'm not sure how to add the categorical constant value to arrive at the final proportion prediction. I tried:

```
proportion = 1/(1+exp(-lp)) + exp(category_constant)
```

but this doesn't give me the result that I get when using the predict function. Could you please help me to interpret how I can derive the proportion, given the coefficients?

Here is my model output:

```
Call:
betareg(formula = PS ~ elevation + DJF + Dry_diff + Wet_diff + SON + 
    1 | basin_name, data = data_train)

Standardized weighted residuals 2:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.1583 -0.6168 -0.1097  0.5028  4.4910 

Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.36040    0.18300 -12.898  < 2e-16 ***
elevation   -4.46786    0.20687 -21.598  < 2e-16 ***
DJF          1.04524    0.29863   3.500 0.000465 ***
Dry_diff     2.66096    0.26908   9.889  < 2e-16 ***
Wet_diff     0.40112    0.08421   4.763 1.90e-06 ***
SON          0.55956    0.10093   5.544 2.95e-08 ***

Phi coefficients (precision model with log link):
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         1.53855    0.09902  15.538  < 2e-16 ***
basin_namebasin_11  0.33296    0.16287   2.044  0.04092 *  
basin_namebasin_12  0.03708    0.16760   0.221  0.82491    
basin_namebasin_13 -0.42456    0.13222  -3.211  0.00132 ** 
basin_namebasin_2   0.37881    0.16305   2.323  0.02016 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood: 691.2 on 11 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.7277
Number of iterations: 24 (BFGS) + 6 (Fisher scoring)
```

Comment: This is very similar to what is done in the following Q&A. The main difference is that the `batch` factor has standard (treatment contrasts) coding: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/472726/how-do-i-compute-beta-regression-response-using-coefficients

Comment: @AchimZeileis thanks for your answer, but I still can't seem to find the right way to use the phi coefficients. I've updated my question with my actual model outputs in case that helps. The predicted values are close to what I get when using the predict function, but I would like to understand exactly how to calculate the predictions given the logit-link  and phi log-link coefficients.

Comment: You have two regression equations: One for the mean proportion (mu), using a logit link. And another one for the corresponding precision parameter (phi), using a log link. See Section 2 in `vignette("betareg", package = "betareg")` for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right: The expected proportion $\mathrm{E}(y) = \mu$ can be computed by applying the inverse link function to the linear predictor $\eta = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot x_1 + \dots + \beta_k \cdot x_k$. For the default logit link you have $\mu = \exp(\eta) / (1 + \exp(\eta))$.

The second submodel for the precision $\phi$ does not affect this first submodel for the expectation $\mu$. But it is relevant for the variance $\mathrm{Var}(y) = \mu \cdot (1 - \mu) / (1 + \phi)$. To compute the precision $\phi$ you also apply the corresponding inverse link function (default link: log) to the corresponding linear predictor with regressors $z_j$ and coefficients $\gamma_j$: $\phi = \exp(\gamma_0 + \gamma_1 \cdot z_1 + \dots + \gamma_l \cdot z_l)$.

Thus in your example:

- $\eta = -2.36040 -4.46786 \cdot \mathtt{elevation} + 1.04524 \cdot \mathtt{DJF} + 2.66096 \cdot \mathtt{Dry\_diff} + 0.40112 \cdot \mathtt{Wet\_diff} + 0.55956 \cdot \mathtt{SON}$.
- $\mu = \exp(\eta)/(1 + \exp(\eta))$.
- $\phi = \exp(1.53855 + 0.33296 \cdot \mathtt{basin\_namebasin\_11} + 0.03708 \cdot \mathtt{basin\_namebasin\_12} - 0.42456 \cdot \mathtt{basin\_namebasin\_13} + 0.37881 \cdot \mathtt{basin\_namebasin\_2}$.
- All the $\mathtt{basin\_namebasin\_*}$ variables are 0/1 indicators for the corresponding category.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. I fully understand now, and I really appreciate you taking the time to explain this in detail. I tried upvoting it but I don't yet have enough points to do so.

Comment: Yes, that is alright. But more importantly please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left. Then the answer is flagged as resolved.

Comment: Thanks, just accepted it.